How to change layout of qualtrics survey so that the question and answer option are adjacent
I am designing a survey in qualtrics. The objecitve is to test participants reading comprehension by asking them to find the answers to questions that are available in an 8 page pdf. I want them to have access to a scrollable version of the PDF on the left side of the browser window. I want the multiple choice questions in Qualtrics to display on the right side of the browser window.
Currently, I have been able to add CSS code into Qualtrics which has allowed me to insert the scrollable PDF into the question area (see code below)
Download here: </span><a href="LINK TO FILE" target="_blank">DRUG NAME.pdf</a><br />

<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> #pdfContainer { width: 100%; height: 450px; /* Adjust the height as per your requirements */ overflow: auto; } #pdfContent { width: 100%; height: 100%; } </style> </head> <body> <div id="pdfContainer"> <iframe id="pdfContent" src="LINK TO FILE"></iframe> </div> </body> </html>
<br> Scroll to page 7 and find the first word on the page
<br>

However, I can't seem to find a way to make the answer layout show as adjacent to the scrollable PDF. See image reference for the current layout, and how I want it to look.
I have tried a number of CSS codes; none of them have worked. Any suggestions?
